# Accessing a django model page using reverse_lazy

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model named `Lal` in Django. I have successfully registered it in my `admin.py` file.

Now , what I want is if a particular url is hit then, I should be able to directly redirect using `reverse_lazy` to the page displaying the model contents that I had registered in `admin.py` file.

The url that gets generated when I access the model displaying template page using my admin-login directly is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/test1_app/lal
```

With the help of this line of code,

```
url(r'yahoo/$', RedirectView.as_view(url = reverse_lazy('admin:app_list',kwargs={'app_label': 'test1_app'})), name="yahoo")
```

I am able to successfully generate  the following url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/test1_app/
```

What should I add more to generate the model's url i.e. this one:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/test1_app/lal
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url name for a model's changelist is `admin:{{ app_label }}_{{ model_name }}_changelist`. So for your app/model you want:

```
reverse_lazy('admin:test1_app_lal_changelist')
```

See the docs on [reversing admin urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-reverse-urls) for more info.